# <script scr='..'> isnt connecting with file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to connect a JS script to my file but non of the files are working.

Main file is called menunew.html
JS file is in a folder called JS/menunew.js

I tried to include type=".."
I tried to place it in the head and body.
I tried using /JS/menunew.js 
I tried using other files in the /JS/ map.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>New menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/menunew.css">
  <script scr="/JS/menunew.js"></script>
</head>
```

I except them to connect.

Comment: Where is your main html file located and where is the JS file located?

Comment: There is no `<script>` tag in the shown HTML. And we don't see where you are calling the function `openSlideMenu()`

Comment: I am sorry for the problems.
I am not showing why i need that function because the problem is that they can't connect

Comment: Typo - `src` not `scr`.

Comment: this isn't the first time i misspelled src.. Haha god damnit!

Comment: @Tais993 I recommend using an IDE (e.g. IntelliJ) with html syntax support, it warns you when you write a tag / attribute that is not recognized.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Googling it would have been faster !

inside your body, just add :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: I had googled it!

But it just didn't work..

I still don't get what I did wrong.. xD

But thanks for the tip! :) It works now!